# How can I automate multiple back-ups of Mac OS, data and archives?

Tags: macos, mac, backup, storage, time-machine

I would like to automatically back up my Mac OS, Data on the Mac, and also Archived data that I only keep on an external storage device (because the mac has limited storage itself).

I imagine the solution will be comprised of Time Machine and one or more external storage devices, but I cannot think of how I would automate the process so that it mimics the `sync` process for an iPhone. Perhaps I need to look outside Time Machine for a solution that meets these needs?

Comment: Time Machine will backup your Mac OS and Data, but to my knowledge, it does not backup data in your external HDD. Do you need to also make a backup of your archive data, or you are happy to leave it on an external drive?

Comment: I recommended [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/) which I use it to exactly what you describe. Tech support, if you need it, is also very good.